How do I find files of a certain extension(s) except in paths that contain certain strings and then print the result to a file?
Upon a little search, I came up with this command:
> find . -type f \( -name "*.exe" \) | egrep -v
> 'games_1|rei|games|tor|jogos|mods|text' > 1

What I wanted to do was find files with the .exe extension, except in paths that contained any of those strings and then print the results to a file named "1", which I wrote into an executable file.
However, upon executing it in the terminal, the following errors occurred and nothing was done:
find: ‘./NUNO-PC/Disco_2TB_120323/Downloads_070321/My Web Sites/wdsdeewre/2.bp.blogspot.com’: Input/output error
find: ‘./NUNO-PC/Disco_2TB_120323/Downloads_070321/My Web Sites/wdsdeewre/segredoh.blogspot.com/feeds’: Input/output error
find: ‘./NUNO-PC/Disco_2TB_120323/Downloads_070321/My Web Sites/wdsdeewre/4.bp.blogspot.com’: Input/output error
find: ‘./NUNO-PC/Disco_2TB_120323/Downloads_070321/My Web Sites/wdsdeewre/3.bp.blogspot.com/-ux8HFQj0iuE/WQ9ywGiPXOI’: Input/output error
grep: write error: Input/output error
./encontrarsoft: error reading input file: Invalid argument

What am I missing?

In any case, an "Input/output error" indicates a problem with your storage - a filesystem corruption, a disk going bad, etc. Nothing to do with your script

The command I used was find . -type f ( -name "*.exe" ) | egrep -v 'games_1|rei|games|tor|jogos|mods|text' > 1
1 is the document I want to write the result into
What I executed was the document I wrote this code into

The errors you show don't really make sense since it seems like grep is trying to read a file but your command wouldn't cause that. In any case, those errors are about problematic files/sectors of your disk and not your command, and you don't need  grep anyway so we can avoid it. By the way, don't use egrep since that is obsolescent, use grep -E instead.
Here is how to do what you want with a single find command:
find . -type f -name '*.exe' \
  -not -regex '.*\(games_1\|rei\|games\|tor\|jogos\|mods\|text\).*'

That will look for files whose name ends in .exe and whose entire path, including the name, doesn't match any of the mentioned strings. The default regular expression language for find is Emacs Regular expressions and in those, you need to escape both ( ) and | for them to have their special meanings of grouping and OR respectively. Alternatively, you can tell find to egrep style regular expressions and simplify to:
find . -regextype egrep -type f -name '*.exe'  \
  -not -regex '.*(games_1|rei|games|tor|jogos|mods|text).*'

(Note that the \  there are just to break the line to avoid horizontal scrolling; the commands can be copy/pasted directly into a terminal as-is, but you could also just do the whole thing on a single line.)
